# Rely on PHPDoc or not? Is there any better type hinting?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I have run in multiple situations where I want autocompletion badly, but only way to specify type of class is to write PHPDoc. Does this approach just smell bad, or I can encounter some serious problems in the future? Here is the code that needs PHPDoc:

```
    /** @var genericTruck $pageObject */
    $pageObject = new $pageClass();

    echo $pageObject->drive();
```

$pageClass is string and can contain class name that is inherited from genericTruck class. Then I need to call methods from that superclass

```
    /** @var truckViewModel $model */
    foreach ($this->view as $model)
    {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>$model->name</td>
                <td><img src='$model->photo'/></td>
            </tr>";
    }
```

Here $this->view is an array, where truckViewModel instances where put by array_push in another class method.

Comment: Your PHP Doc comments are wrong, at least PHP Storm doesn't recognize them.
But PHP Storm do recognize this

`/* @var $model truckViewModel */`

Comment: Which version of PHPStorm you use? I have PHPStorm 9 and Eclipse Mars.1, both work with no problem

Comment: @MathewB. NetBeans (at least prior versions as I switched to PhpStorm a year ago) wouldn't handle the PHPDoc-style comments with two asterisks, insisting on one for inline comments. PhpStorm 10.0.3 handles both one and two asterisks (just tested).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is exactly how you should do it. In the case of `$pageObject` where it is a variable type, you should hint a common ancestor or interface that all types would extend or implement.

I'm unsure that `genericTruck` follows class naming convention standards the best it can (should be `Generic_Truck` or `GenericTruck` etc as per most guidelines), but that's your decision.

There is nothing weird or fishy about relying on PHPDoc for type hinting or guidelines. It's common practice to use it and it's not going away any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can type hint this way; but there is a better way to document what you're trying to achieve.

Presumably `$pageClass` is injected somewhere and unless you've validation over this any calling code could inject something else.  For example you might be expecting something of base type `Model` but instead be given `CompletelyUnrelatedClass` and thus your $pageObject` is rather unreliable.

In this case, you're best off type hinting on a base interface that exhibits the minimum behaviour for your function/object to work.

Here's a contrived example

```
class MyClass{
  public function doDrivingWith(\MyCode\DrivableInterface $drivable)
  {
    //... do things with $drivable.
  }

  //... or with your specific example:
  public function renderSomething() {
    /* @var \MyCode\RenderableInterface $pageObject */
    $pageObject = new $pageClass;
    // $pageObject->anyRenderableMethods(); // only call methods from the interface.
  }
}
```

In theory, your code should only call methods that the `DrivableInterface` defines.

This leads the way to be able to use [dependency injection](http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-dependency-injection.html) rather than variable classes names to instantiate your objects which is generally considered much cleaner.

Comment: The question is about autocompletion of class names, not about type hinting or interface-like type restrictions

Comment: Absolutely. However the relevance is around code smells and improving implementation; hence the context.  I don't at all refute the ability to do type variable hinting in that manner; rather improve it.

Comment: Totally agree with that!